# How to assert that a BigNumber is included in a list of numbers?

Tags: hardhat, testing, bignumber, chai, assert

I am trying to assert a `uint256` the following way:

```
            expect(tokenType).to.be.oneOf([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

I just want to check that its value is any of the ones on that list, as I am using a randomisation to get it and I want to check that it is working properly.

The problem I have is that I am getting this error:

```
AssertionError: expected BigNumber { value: "3" } to be one of [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [`chai` documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-bn/), `oneOf` assertion does not work with `BigNumber`.

I had to replace that assertion with `greaterThan` and `lessThan`:

```
expect(tokenType).to.be.greaterThan(BigNumber.from(0)).and.lessThan(BigNumber.from(5));
```